# The program doesn't stop when I enter "-1", it goes to the following "printf". Why?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    float gallons, miles, tot=0, cont=0, average=0, division;

    while(gallons != -1){
        printf("Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): ");
        scanf("%f", &gallons);
        printf("Enter the miles driven: ");
        scanf("%f", &miles);
        division = miles/gallons;
        printf("The miles / gallon for this tank was %.2f\n", division);
        cont++;
        tot+=division;
    }

    average=tot/cont;

    printf("The overall average miles / gallons was %.2f\n", average);

    return 0;
}
```

The program doesn't stop when I enter "-1", it goes to the following "printf". Why?

Comment: You scan at the beginning of the loop. It won't exit before it checks the value of gallons at the beginning of the next loop.

Comment: It is *undefined behaviour* since `gallons` is uninitialiased.

Comment: If you want to exit your loop after entering a value, maybe you should do that rather than continuing with the rest of the loop body. And pay close attention to what @WeatherVane said. Also, once you fix your problem and leave early consider how to address the potential code path of division-by-zero if the *first* data entered was `-1`.

Comment: Using `while(gallons != -1)` does not attach some kind of **usage monitor** to that variable. It is tested there and then, by that code statement, and at no other place. That's why the next `printf` statement is executed.

Comment: Learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: It's not uncommon among beginners to expect a loop to exit as soon as the condition becomes false (and I think it's a natural expectation), but that 's not how it works – the condition is only checked at the beginning of each loop iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you looking for something like below.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {

        float gallons =0, miles= 0, tot=0, cont=0, average=0, division;

      printf("Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): ");
            scanf("%f", &gallons);

        while(gallons != -1){

            printf("Enter the miles driven: ");
            scanf("%f", &miles);
            division = miles/gallons;
            printf("The miles / gallon for this tank was %.2f\n", division);
            cont++;
            tot+=division;

    printf("Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): ");
            scanf("%f", &gallons);
        }

        average=tot/cont;

        printf("The overall average miles / gallons was %.2f\n", average);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: A true average is the sum of the miles divided by the sum of the gallons. Not the sum of the averages divided by the number of trips.